# using multiple robots with the same roscore on multiple machines

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I have 2 robots with the same code. They are running on multiple machines(each robot on one machine).
I have one node that needs to sync the data between them.
The question is, how I change the topics on the launch so that each robot will work with its own topics and still be able to configure the topic of the syncing node so it will be able to subscribe from the second robot topics.
I'm using ROS 1 Kinetic

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/375011/using-multiple-robots-with-the-same-roscore-on-multiple-machines/) by [os](https://answers.ros.org/users/33098/os/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2021-03-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To the best of knowledge, ROS graph isolation in ROS1 relies on namespaces. So if you've consistently used relative names, you should be able to `<include/>` an entire launch file hierarchy from within a `<group/>`, which allows you to set a namespace (see http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/group). If you haven't, or if you rely on code that doesn't (e.g. `tf2` is likely hitting `/tf` and `/tf_static`), you can explicitly `<remap/>` within each group (see http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/remap). Some node in the root namespace can then target any topic using fully qualified names.

---

Originally posted by [hidmic](https://answers.ros.org/users/24051/hidmic/) with karma: 121 on 2021-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [os](https://answers.ros.org/users/33098/os/) on 2021-03-31**:
Is there a way to this globally without edit each launch file? In my project, I have multiple lanch and I try to find out if there is an easy way to do this?

Can the remapping/group adding be done dynamically?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-03-31**:
Dynamic remapping is not supported in ROS 1. There are plans for ROS 2. But I believe you're not necessarily asking for remapping at runtime, only remapping without editing files.

Remapping launch files can be done external to the `.launch` file, by adding an `ns` attribute to the `include` element.

**Comment by [os](https://answers.ros.org/users/33098/os/) on 2021-03-31**:
@gvdhoorn So in order to avoid editing all my `.launch` files, I need to create a new launch that will load the others, and in that primary launch add the `ns` attribute?

**Comment by [hidmic](https://answers.ros.org/users/24051/hidmic/) on 2021-03-31**:
That's about right. Moreover, if the same launch files are deployed to different robots, launch arguments and/or `$(env)` substitutions are a simple way to parameterize and reuse the same top-level `.launch`.